# DocumentDB - embed vs reference vs middle way

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I'm modeling DocumentDB database and trying to figure out optimal way for a particular problem.
Lets illustrate it with an `Order > OrderLine > Product example.`

So, `Order` has `OrderLines` and `OrderLines` contain `Products`. (logically)

in documentDB, `Order` can be represented, for example, like this:

```
{
  id,
  title,
  date,
  lines:
  [
    { orderLineId, productId, name, quantity, price  },
    { orderLineId, productId, name, quantity, price  },
    { orderLineId, productId, name, quantity, price  }
  ]
}
```

In this case, `OrderLines` are embeded and `Products` are referenced (with an addition of `name` field being a snapshot of `Product` name at the time of `OrderLine` being created).

Now we come to a query: `How much of a Product with id=abc have i sold between date1 and date2?`

In this setup, that query should go through all `Orders` > `OrderLines` to find `productId` in a given line. Sounds like not optimal.
Other solution would be to flatten the document by referencing `OrderLines` instead of embeding them into `Order`. That's good for this query but then querying full `Order` turns into 2 queries.

Third option would be to keep `numberOfSales` record in `Product` document so that we keep `runningBalance` per product. That requires 2 step write for each `Order` creation: one for order itself and one update of `Products` document.

At the moment i lean mostly towars third solution with running balance for each product but not sure if i'm missing something? Are there any big problems with that? Or, is there some recommended/better/other way of doing it?

Comment: >>" That's good for this query but then querying full Order turns into 2 queries." - if u put those 2 into same partition you can write stored procedure which will execute those 2 more fast... With 3rd option - you will need take care that your `order`'s data is consistent to the `product.numberOfSales` data.. I think the way depends on how often you need to execute each type of query.. Btw, there's a FeedChange option, using which u can subscribe to docs changes in your collection and based on this - update your `product.numberOfSales` property - so you ends up with 1 call on order creation

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, the best way to do this, is to **start with the most important thing - identifying PartitionKey**. It affects so many aspects of the development, so it's something worth to look into in the first place before building the rest of your schema. There are certain rules to this -

1. Make sure that with your PartitionKey allows you to distribute requests over partitions rather than ending up with a "hot" one. Choosing a partition key with higher cardinality is generally preferred.
2. Since PartitionKey defines a scope for effective queries and transactions, select the one that will allow you to narrow down your requests so to avoid cross-partitions/fan-out requests.
3. Forecast your needs in terms of the storage and throughput. Keep in mind that logical partitions cannot grow beyond the maximum logical partition limit of 10 GB.

Other from that, you also **need to understand your workload**. For read-heavy one, think about your top queries, like the ones that get executed more than others or(-and) deal with huge portions of data. For write-heavy workload, think about transactions and updates vs inserts (as to my knowledge, there is no such thing as partial update yet).

And now comes the moment to **start designing nuances of your schema**. So in general, develop the scheme that will comply with the aforementioned best practices. If you end up with multiple options, go with the one that "suits" you more :)

---

Here is an example of how you could design your schema.

- Leave Order collection as is, making orderid your PartitionKey.
- Get another collection where you would keep your product records, with productionid as PartitionKey.
- Now, create a third collection - ProductOrders, where you will place record per each product-order combination and make productid PartionKey of the collection - {productid, orderid,date, ...}.

It gives you - **a)** one query to get order details **b)** the query to count amount of the purchased product for a given time-range could be narrowed down to a single partion. Assuming you have index against Date field, the performance of the query should satisfy you. **c)** There is [bulk-api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/bulk-executor-overview) for inserting multiple records into the third collection, which you may want to look into. **d)** no need to update(replace and insert) product record each time you have a new order. **e)** a tradeoff, of course, is to sync up Orders and ProductOrders collections on your own, and a small(?) amount of data duplication.

It's just one of many options. In case of small rate of writes and tremendous amount of orders, you may even create a collection for each year-month combination. Understanding best practices, your production workload and experiments should lead you to the best solution.